# No such file or directory: 'docker': 'docker' when running sagemaker studio in local mode

Tags: docker, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I try to train a pytorch model on amazon sagemaker studio.

It's working when I use an EC2 for training with:

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='train_script.py',
                role=role,
                sagemaker_session = sess,
                train_instance_count=1,
                train_instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge',
                framework_version='1.4.0', 
                source_dir='.',
                git_config=git_config, 
               )
estimator.fit({'stockdata': data_path})
```

and it's work on local mode in classic sagemaker notebook (non studio) with:

```
 estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='train_script.py',
                role=role,
                train_instance_count=1,
                train_instance_type='local',
                framework_version='1.4.0', 
                source_dir='.',
                git_config=git_config, 
               )
estimator.fit({'stockdata': data_path})
```

But when I use it the same code (with train_instance_type='local') on sagemaker studio it doesn't work and I have the following error: No such file or directory: 'docker': 'docker'

I tried to install docker with pip install but the docker command is not found if use it in terminal

Comment: Now possible to install docker OS package in KGW app
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78009634/15674095

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This indicates that there is a problem finding the Docker service.

By default, the Docker is not installed in the SageMaker Studio  ([confirming github ticket response](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/656#issuecomment-632170943)).

Answer (score 4):

Adding more information to an almost 2 years old question.

SageMaker Studio does not natively support `local mode`. Studio Apps are themselves docker containers and therefore they require `privileged` access if they were to be able to build and run docker containers.

As an alternative solution, you can create a remote docker host on an EC2 instance and setup docker on your Studio App. There is quite a bit of networking and package installation involved, but the solution will enable you to use full docker functionality. Additionally, as of version `2.80.0` of [SageMaker Python SDK](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/v2.80.0/src/sagemaker/local/utils.py#L133-L154), it now supports `local mode` when you are using remote docker host.

<strike>`sdocker`</strike>`SageMaker Studio Docker CLI extension` (see this [repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-docker-cli-extension)) can simplify deploying the above solution in simple two steps (only works for Studio Domain in `VPCOnly` mode) and it has an easy to follow example [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-docker-cli-extension/blob/main/example/sagemaker-studio-local-mode.ipynb).

**UPDATE:**
There is now a UI extension (see [repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-docker-ui-extension)) which can make the experience much smoother and easier to manage.
[image: sdocker UI]

Comment: Hi @Sam Edwards, appreciate the time you have taken to bring in more context. Would you have a GitHub link that works in 2022?

Comment: @Lihka_nonem I have updated my reply. Now it is included under AWS samples repo with a UI extension that makes it easier to use and manage