# Is it possible to use docker commands in Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

It is not possible to install docker in the SageMaker Studio. Is there a way to install and use it?

```
$ sudo yum install docker
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Docker engine in Sagemaker Studio is not supported. Use [SageMaker Docker Build CLI](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli) as described in [Using the Amazon SageMaker Studio Image Build CLI to build container images from your Studio notebooks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-the-amazon-sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli-to-build-container-images-from-your-studio-notebooks/)

Answer (score 0):

The CLI for Amazon SageMaker Studio Image Build enables the creation of Amazon SageMaker-compatible Docker images directly within your Amazon SageMaker Studio environments.

Below are the commands for installing and the docker image creation:

```
!pip install sagemaker-studio-image-build

!sm-docker build . --repository < ecr-repo-name >:< image-name >
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to run docker commands and build images within Kernel gateway app post enabling docker settings inside studio domain.

Documentation to enable docker - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-updated-local.html

Docker package installation steps for different OS on which kernel gateway app might be hosted
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/tree/main/sagemaker_studio_docker_cli_install